# Programmatically create a product using Craft Commerce 2?

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2

The [docs for v1](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/purchasables) mention a method `craft()->commerce_purchasables->saveElement()`.

This is omitted in the [docs for v2](https://github.com/craftcms/commerce-docs). Does anyone know how I can create a product programmatically in PHP?

```
    $product = new Product();
        $product->title = "Test Product 1";
        $product->typeId = 2;
        $product->enabled = true;
        $product->promotable = true;

    $variant = new Variant();
            $variant->isDefault = true;

    $product->setVariants([$variant]);

    Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($product);
```

With the above code I get the following error:

```
Call to a member function getProductTypes() on null
```

I know the typeId is correct, because I can output it on a product template with `{{ product.typeId }}`

Answer (score 3):

You probably have it figured by now, but for anyone wondering, here's a complete working example.

```
use craft\commerce\elements\Product;
use craft\commerce\elements\Variant;

// Create product
$product = new Product();
$product->title = 'Hello world';
$product->typeId = 2;
$product->enabled = true;

// Create variant
$variant = new Variant();
$variant->title = 'hey';
$variant->sku = 'hey';
$variant->price = 123;
$variant->stock = 5;

// Save product with variant
$product->setVariants([$variant]);
Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($product);
```

Comment: hey thank you. this helped me a lot and was working great until a recent update. any idea what has changed? i think my product is no longer validating for some (new) reason.

Answer (score 1):

1. Populate a product model (`$product`)
2. Populate an array of variant models (`$variants`)
3. `$product->setVariants($variants);`
4. `Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($product);`

If step 4 returns false, validation errors occurred on the variants or product, and the errors be on the `$product`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm getting the error `Call to a member function getProductTypes() on null` when I try to run my code. I've updated my question to add the code I'm trying.